# No XmlDocument and XDocument in VS2010 Express for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I use MS Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone to build the app. In my app,  I got the http respond and read it in string then I deserializer into the class object.  It works fine in the class without List collection as a property.  When it deserializer the class with List property, it got the error like this

```
Error in line 12 position 5. Expecting state  'Element'.. Encountered 'EndElement'  with name  'ContactList', namespace  'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataObjects’.
```

I think I can read the xml and assign the value into the class. I searched  to read  xml file and a lot of website mentions to use XDocument .Prase  method or xlmDocument.Load. However event  adding the  System.Xml.Ling as reference , I still cannot see XDocument .Parse  method or xlmDocument . Would someone tell me what I should do in order to assign the following value into the class?

There is my class object:

```
public class CallDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string errorMsg { get; set; }
    public int parentCallid { get; set; }
    public string parentCallURL { get; set; }
    public string assignedTo { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
    public DateTime onHoldSince { get; set; }
    public DateTime onHoldUntil { get; set; }
    public string requester { get; set; }
    public bool isOnHold { get; set; }
    private List<Contact> m_ContactList = new List<Contact>();

    public List<Contact> ContactList
    {
        get { return m_ContactList; }

    }
}
```

There is the respond:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CallDetails xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataObjects">
<ContactList>
      <Contact>
          <Method>PriPhone</Method>
          <Number>(604) 555-1234</Number>
      </Contact>
      <Contact>
          <Method>Fax</Method>
          <Number>(604)555-1234</Number>
      </Contact>
  </ContactList>
  <errorMsg
      i:nil="true" />
  <id>0</id>
  <isOnHold>false</isOnHold>
  <onHoldSince>0001-01-01T00:00:00</onHoldSince>
  <onHoldUntil>0001-01-01T00:00:00</onHoldUntil>
  <parentCallURL>/Call/349551</parentCallURL>
  <parentCallid>0</parentCallid>
  <requester>Peter </requester>  
  <summary>Mobile Application Research</summary>
</CallDetails>
```

Comment: Although I usually encourage people to provide enough information with the question, you have included _too much_. Your problem has nothing to do with the contents of the XML document, or with serialization. Your problem was a compilation error with your use of XDocument.Parse.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I do not have XDocument.Parse in my code that why I asked how I have it. I used DataContractSerializer.ReadObject to do the serializer. If the class without List<Contact>, it is no error.

Comment: To be clear, I was referring to you saying "I still cannot see XDocument .Parse method". Not a compile error, but still has nothing to do with your code logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the reference to `System.Xml.Linq` won't do it, you also need to reference the namespace in the class header:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then you can call something like `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(content);`. However, from what I can tell, you are trying to deserialize data, so you might want to use the `XmlSerializer` class instead for all the core work. You can find some code 'ispiration' [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/serializing-and-deserializing).

Comment: I had it, but it still doesn't have XDocument.Parse.

Comment: What do you get in IntelliSense when you type `XDocument doc = XDocument.`(screenshot welcome)?

Comment: Just in case your IntelliSense is broken, what happens if you just write `string parseMe = "<a/>";var doc = XDocument.Parse(parseMe);`? Does that compile?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, After I tried your example, I can see XDocument.Parse.  When I created a new XDocument, there waw no Parse. Thanks.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky, there is my code to cause the error that I post. using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(content)))
            {
               // var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(r);
                var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                var deserializedItem = (T)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
                reader.Close();
                return deserializedItem;
            }

        }

Comment: @YChan: `Parse` is a static method. The following will not work: `var doc = new XDocument(); doc.Parse(string);` It must be `XDocument.Parse(string);`

Answer (score 0):

I found it that the CallDetail Class cause error.  It should be like that

```
 public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
```